# JavaScript setting variables with a constructor

Tags: javascript, variables, nested-function

I was trying to set a variable in a constructor function that can be called by nested function expression. not too sure on how to do this

```js
var test = function() {
  var a;

  function test(a, b, c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;

  }
  test.getvariableA = function() {
    //not returning a variable that is supposed to be set by the constructor
    console.log(this.a);
  };
  return test;
}();

var t = new test("pizza", "pasta", "steak");
//does not return the variable
test.getvariableA();
//this returns the variable
console.log(t.a);
```

> test.getvariableA();

This should be returning the variable set by the constructor. Maybe I'm confused with another language 
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you able to use es6? This may be helpful for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @chevybow Nope . I have to keep the structure as is without going over to class based declaration

Comment: What exactly do you think `new test` returns? Try renaming your variables. After that, just step through the code and see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> this returns the variable: `console.log(t.a);`

Right, so the property is on the `t` instance.

But your `test.getvariableA` function doesn't know about `t` at all! It does try to access `test.a` when you are invoking `test.getvariableA()`.

You may be looking to put the method on the prototype object of your class, not the constructor itself. That way it will be inherited by all instances (like `t`), and you can call it on `t` to get `t.a`:

```
var test = function() {
  // var a; - this is not used anywhere, drop it

  function test(a, b, c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;

  }
  test.prototype.getVariableA = function() {
//    ^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(this.a);
  };
  return test;
}();

var t = new test("pizza", "pasta", "steak");
t.getVariableA(); /*
^ */
console.log(t.a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are defining the `getvariableA` outside of the constructor and attaching it to the function `test` instead. Therefore the `getvariableA` is a "public" method and does not point to the `t` instance you created (or any other instance you would create using the `new` keyword).

In other words `this` inside of the `test.getvariableA` points to the function constructor itself, not any specific instance of this constructor (`t` in your example).

When yo attach a method to the function outside of the constructor you can access it without creating new instances. If you `console.log(test.getvariableA)` you can see you have access to this method without creating `new` instances whereas `console.log(test.a)` shows undefined as `a` is assigned to each new instance of the class.

Hope this clarifies it at least a bit, sorry if it's not clear.